# Why does Orpheus know how to find Destruction?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, the-sandman

Yes they are family, but why is Orpheus the only oracle who could lead Dream and Delirium to find Destruction?

Comment: Was it really *only* Orpheus? Or was he just the most accessible of all the people who would know where Destruction is?

Comment: @ToddWilcox before that only during cat queen - dream discussion mentioned sphinx. actually who is sphinx ? and... why Dream thinks that Orpheus knows the location of Destruction? and why Orpheus does?

Comment: As an **oracle**, Orpheus would know and/or be able to learn things using oracular powers. That's what it means to be an oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Todd Wilcox notes, it is an oracle's job to know things others don't know. In ancient Greece (as the myths tell) it was common to consult an oracle on occasions when it was crucial to make the right decision.

Why only Orpheus? When Destiny suggests they seek an oracle, Morpheus tells him there is no oracle capable of "seeing" their family, thus stating that the Endless are above the ordinary oracles' competence. Orpheus, however, being the son of Dream of the Endless and a muse, is not an ordinary being in any way. Being of Endless descent, he appears to able to "see" his family, at least to Destiny's and Morpheus' minds.

---

From a story-developing perspective, Morpheus had to see Orpheus and do what he did because this enables the rest often series to evolve. (**spoilers** for the end of the series) Neil Gaiman said in *The Sandman Companion* that this is a point of no return - if before that moment Gaiman had "escape hatches" built in to take the series in a different direction, after Morpheus kills his son he seals his fate, which results in his own death at the end.

Comment: It's really a rather critical moment in the story. Somewhere in the back of my head was the limitation on all the other oracles' abilities to see the Endless, but I couldn't bring it forward and really remember it to write the answer to the actual question. +1

Comment: thx for the explanation. now i realize that "it was common to consult an oracle on occasions when it was crucial to make the right decision". in my hometown it's also ppl consult from blind ppl, previously i wasnt thinking "blind ppl can't even see the physical road, how could they tell the fortune?" now it occurred to me that it might be in old days simple survival is sort of an oracle for blind ppl, so ppl who can see, when they are confused in life, will seek help from blind ones. that does make sense.